# Plugin getDataFolder null pointer

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm working on a Bukkit plugin at the moment with a few other people, and I'm attempting to create a log system. I've been trying to fix my broken code for 2 days, and have gotten nowhere. The part that it seems to be getting stuck on is where I get the data folder for the plugin so I can move on and write to a file in the folder.

Stacktrace:

```
[18:41:07] [Server thread/ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling TownyEco v1.0-SNAPSHOT (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at com.writedive.townyeco.TownyEco.onEnable(TownyEco.java:67) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:264) ~[spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-4bd94dc-fb414fe]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:337) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-4bd94dc-fb414fe]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:403) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-4bd94dc-fb414fe]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:381) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-4bd94dc-fb414fe]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:330) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-4bd94dc-fb414fe]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.t(MinecraftServer.java:422) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-4bd94dc-fb414fe]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.l(MinecraftServer.java:383) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-4bd94dc-fb414fe]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:338) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-4bd94dc-fb414fe]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:272) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-4bd94dc-fb414fe]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:545) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-4bd94dc-fb414fe]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_161]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.writedive.townyeco.messaging.TELogWriter.getRootFolder(TELogWriter.java:12) ~[?:?]
    at com.writedive.townyeco.messaging.TELogWriter.<clinit>(TELogWriter.java:14) ~[?:?]
    ... 12 more
```

Error coming from:

```
private static TownyEco plugin;
private static String getRootFolder() {
    return plugin.getDataFolder().getPath();
}
private static String PATH = getRootFolder() + File.separator + "logs";
```

Inside of the main class, logger referenced from in onEnable:

```
TELogWriter.log("Initialized", TELogWriter.LogType.STARTUP);
```

What do I do to fix the issue?

Main Class: [TownyEco.java](https://github.com/Articdive/TownyEco/blob/master/src/main/java/com/writedive/townyeco/TownyEco.java)

Logger Class: [TELogWriter.java](https://github.com/Articdive/TownyEco/blob/master/src/main/java/com/writedive/townyeco/messaging/TELogWriter.java)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is not a good idea to post link to entire of you classes. People wont spend time in visiting those links and read through your classes. Best way is to put specific pieces of code here and ask specific question. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Edited to try and avoid that @AmitPhaltankar

Answer (score 2):

plugin in TELogWriter is never initialized, so below code is throwing NPE

```
private static String getRootFolder() {
    return plugin.getDataFolder().getPath();
}
```

Initialize TELogWriter.plugin in TownyEco.java then call the log

```
TELogWriter.plugin = plugin;
TELogWriter.log("Initialized", TELogWriter.LogType.STARTUP);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with the API you are using but,

A) if getDataFolder() is returning null only sometimes, due to an inconsitency

```
private static String getRootFolder() {
    FolerObjectTypeOfTheAPI path;
    if (plugin != null && (path = plugin.getDataFolder()) != null)  {
        return path.getPath();
    }
    return null; // or you can return "";
}
```

B) If always null, then the path specified in "getDataFolder()" is most likely not the correct path on your file system